# What is the term for when a song switches to a wall of sound, often with a rising chromatic scale, and often found at the end of a song?

Tags: terminology, musical-forms, coda

You often hear this at the end of songs when the lyrics end and it becomes a 'wall of sound' for want of a better term. Here's an example:

Here's another example:

It's very common in live music.

Does it have a musical name?

Comment: I can't answer your question, but I want to point out that neither of those examples are really using a chromatic scale.  They are both using a handful of chords outside the key (sometimes called chromatic chords).

Comment: Mostly it’s just going for a climax at the very end, even if using a somewhat repetitive structure.  A similar principle as here, in probably one of the biggest endings ever conceived: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ObqeWK7lKc0&t=3940s

Comment: Personally I call it a *grand finale.*  ("Finale pronounced in the Italian way, with three syllables.)  I don't know if there's a special term in pop music, though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

These could be in line with what Brad Osborn coined "terminally climactic forms" in [this article](https://academic.oup.com/mts/article-abstract/35/1/23/1056491?login=false). He states that a TCF is

> not a chorus but a single, thematically independent section placed at the end [that] functions as the song's most memorable moment. (23)

Although an ascending chromatic scale is not a requirement in a TCF, Osborn does state that these climaxes often include, among other things, the highest and/or lowest pitches in the song. As such, an ascending chromatic scale is simply one manifestation of this standard parameter of the TCF that helps make it so memorable.

I invite anyone interested in this to read the article. Brad's a terrific scholar, and it's some great research.

Answer (score 0):

There could be more than one way to notated a much sudden wall of sound. Crescendo with molto or subito. Meaning much and suddenly. Crescendo could be omitted and replaced with a molto and subito Forte

Answer (score 0):

No, there isn't an accepted term.

You could call it a 'Rock-out' perhaps?   As distinct from a 'Fade-out'.  (Though a recording might do both at once!'.

Comment: You don't like 'Rock-out'?  Fair enough.  But it IS an answer.

Comment: Will prefacing my suggestion with 'No, there isn't an accepted term.' make you happy?  OK, here you are.

Comment: I didn't vote, but... You *could* call it a rock out.  But no one would know what you're talking about without an explanation.

Comment: @Edward Which, is why I led with 'No, there isn't an accepted term.'.